# C# SQL SELECT WHERE <variable> LIKE %Column% - format?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Currently I am using this statement:

```
"SELECT categoryDB, number FROM " + dbName+ " WHERE titleDBColumn ='" + titleInput+ "'";
```

Which helps me find strings that are similar to titleInput (which is a variable coming from the outside).

However, the values in titleDBColumn are almost always shorter strings than those coming in through titleInput.

Example:

```
titleDBColumn: Streetcar
titleInput: TheStreetCarIOwn
```

Now it's obvious that I need to use the LIKE operator in the other direction to get the results I want but I cant get the format right. Any ideas?
Sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: Well start by showing us what you have tried while not getting the syntax right please

Comment: `dbName = "; DROP DATABASE " + dbName + ";";` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @ChrisPickford Exactly. OP, you need to fix your [SQL Injection vulnerability](https://scottlilly.com/common-c-vulnerabilities-sql-injection/).

Comment: Note that if we put aside the SQL injection problem, this looks more like an SQL question than a C# question

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
"SELECT categoryDB, number FROM " + dbName + " WHERE '" +
titleInput + "' like '%" + titleDBColumn + "%'";
```

Comment: I get an error near  '%' + titleDBColumn + '%' which I was expecting, why are we still using the "+" and quotes inside already established quotation?

Comment: The purpose is to concatenate the percent symbols to the titleDBColumn field. It should work as long as the field is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting SQL must be

```
SELECT categoryDB, number
FROM tableName
WHERE 'input' LIKE '%' + titleDBColumn + '%'
```

The `%` wildcard means "any number of any characters". I.e, `'input' LIKE '%' + titleDBColumn + '%'` means that the input text may contain characters before and after the column text.

Also, you should use command parameters, whenever possible. This is not possible for the table name you called `dbName`. If this name is defined in the code and is not a user input, then it is safe to concatenate it as you did. But otherwise take measures to prevent SQL-Injection.

```
string sql = "SELECT categoryDB, number FROM `" + dbName +
         "` WHERE @input LIKE '%' + titleDBColumn + '%'";
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr)) {
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", titleInput);

    conn.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, parameters are required to protect from SQL Injection